# Retrieve data with the linq query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have table **StudentAccount** with columns Code,Amount,Description,Valid Period 
for selected period there might be same code and description 
write a linq query that gets the data Code/Description needs to be unique for the selected date range.( the date is in the format 1/1/1990-1/1/1991)

```
    public IEnumerable<StudentAccount> StudentAccountdata
    {
        get { return Context.StudentAccount.Where(q=>q.Active).OrderBy(q =>q.Description).ToList(); }            
    }
```

Comment: how can u say like this..if u can answer it fine..dont make silly comments..problem can be small or big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IEqualityComparer` like so:

```
public class StdComparer : IEqualityComparer<StudentAccount>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<StudentAccount> Members

    public bool Equals(StudentAccount x, StudentAccount y)
    {
        return x.Code == y.Code && x.Description == y.Description;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(StudentAccount obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then

```
public IEnumerable<StudentAccount> StudentAccountdata
{
    get { return Context.StudentAccount.Where(q=>q.Active && 
                    q.Date >= BeginDate && 
                    q.Date <= EndDate)
                   .OrderBy(q =>q.Description).Distinct(new StdComparer()); }
}
```